# Camera with custom shutter sound

Tags: android, android-camera

I have a custom `camera` implementation which I would like to have have my own sound when the picture is taken using API 10. I have the following code which does `play my sound` but it also plays the default camera sound as well, I need to only play my camera sound and not the default one.

```
   //takes picture
   mCamera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);

   ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        MediaPlayer.create(SecondCamera.this,R.raw.camera_click).start();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
      camera.enableShutterSound(false);

}
else{
        AudioManager audio= (AudioManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        currentVolume=audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);            
        audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 0,   AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
        MediaPlayer media= MediaPlayer.create(SecondCamera.this,R.raw.camera_click);
        media.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
        isVolumeChanged=true;           
     }
```

Do the above before `onShutter()` then call `media.start()` on `onShutter()`

then on `onPictureTaken()` Do the following.

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {


        if (isVolumeChanged){
            audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,currentVolume,AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!!!!!